# Facebook via-Link not work (Misconfigured App or not clickable)

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-timeline

I get this message from Facebook if I click on the via "my App" link on desktop facebook site:

> Misconfigured App Sorry, the details for "your app" cannot be
>   displayed because the app is misconfigured.

The via-Link is not clickable on mobile Facebook App and on mobile facebook site.
Where is the difference?

Facebook works with our app, only the via-link don't work.
What settings are needed for the via "my App" link?

[image]

**Screenshots from my Facebook developer console:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not enough information to help you. Post screenshots of your settings in the facebook developer console. When does the issue happen (also:screenshots)? From your tags i guess that the issue is related to the facebook unity sdk, but that's just a guess. Also what is the relation to the facebook-timeline tag?

Comment: I use the Neatplug Facebook SDK, not the official Facebook-Unity-SDK. http://www.neatplug.com/unity3d-plugins-android

The bug is on the users timeline, this is the relation for the timeline tag.

Comment: now I posted screenshots from my facebook developer console.

Comment: Is your app actually enabled? You can see this in the Status section.

Comment: Yes my App "is public and available to all users"

Comment: the screenshots are pretty useless if you hide all the relevant information...

Comment: But which informations are important? In all hide fields is entered something. Facebook works with our app, only the via-link don't work.

Comment: Is your App Details tab filled in? did you submit the App Details page for approval for app center?

Comment: Yes the app details are filled, but unapproved. Is this the problem? I will check this.. Thank you!

Comment: Did you correctly put App Id in unity engine of facebook editor settings?
check all these type of small things.

Comment: Yes I put the App ID correctly in Unity.